# ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda` or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I need conda environment to run some python repositiory. Earlier I had code in my windows PC, I installed the Anaconda shell and every thing else was good to go.. easy peasy!!

But, now I have moved to the code to the server(because of memory requirements). Im using Putty client to access that server and all the operations must be performed using the Putty shell. How do I run conda from there? I installed conda using **pip install conda** but every time I try to run conda command, it throws following error

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

upon searching, I found out that the conda that is being installed using pip is corrupted. so I went ahead and installed mini conda as per the instructions in the following link:

```
https://mediawiki.middlebury.edu/CS/Useful_Tools
```

It did install the miniconda smoothly but if it try to run it still gives me same error as above.
can any one help? do I need to unistall the conda which I installed using pip?

Answer (score 3):

You need to reopen the terminal for the changes to take effect!

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I don't have enough reputations to comment

Comment: You now have the commenting privilege. And well-earned it seems, because this was considered a helpful answer (and reads at least like an answer to me). But please undestand that not having the privilege does not mean that answering posts can be misused as comments. Just in case you explain StackOverflow to others... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall the first installation of conda. It seems like you didn't that's why every time you run conda you get the same error because it refers to the first installation one. If you did uninstall it and you still get the error make sure to add miniconda to PATH.

Answer (score 0):

**The better option is reinstall anaconda.**

Download the installer.
[https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads]](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads%5D)

Create an anaconda folder
mkdir

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh

Go to your home directory
cd ~

Tape
sha256sum /home/username/anaconda/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh

Go to Anaconda Folder.
cd anaconda

tapr
ash Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh

Select yes for all installation options.

Check the installation:
conda --v